# Defining dynamic variable for selector to loop on in $.each

Tags: jquery, each

I have the following jquery code:

```
$.each(test1, function (key, value) {
            //do something
        });
```

the value test is a array of json object.

```
    var test1 = [{ "id": "0", "elementId": "slice10"},
 { "id": "2", "elementId": "slice12"},
 { "id": "3", "elementId": "slice13"}];
```

Similar to this array I have more array like test2, test3,test4...

Is there a way I can dynamically substitute the value of array in the $.each loop.
Something like:

```
Var i=2;

$.each(**"test"+i**, function (key, value) {
                //do something
            });
```

Thanks.

Comment: Put your `$.each()` inside a `for` loop.

Comment: `$.each([test1, test2, test3], function (key, value) { ...` ???

Comment: No, but you could store each of those separate arrays in another array and loop over it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an `Object` of your arrays and access its fields with `Object[property]` notation:

```
var someObject = {
   test1: ["some", "values", "here"],
   test2: ["some", "values", "here"],
   test3: ["some", "values", "here"]
}

var index = 2;

$.each(someObject["test" + index], function (key, value) {
                //do something
            });
```

Comment: This looks promising. Will try this and confirm if it solves my problem. Thank you.